# How to deal with enums that aren't really enums because they can be changed?

Tags: java, database-design, web-applications, hsqldb

I'm working on a web app for a class.  It's basically a project management system, similar to a watered down version of Bugzilla, but specifically tailored for an academic environment.  One of the requirements is that for a number of settings (such as project type which could be master's project, PhD thesis, etc.) the lists of possible values be configurable.  So there would be a configuration or settings page where you could change the values in each list, but then in the rest of the app (like when creating a project or task) the values in the list will be the only options to choose from.  Also if you change one of the values (say from master's paper to master's thesis) all the records which use that value should have it changed, too.  So all projects marked as master's paper would now be marked as master's thesis.

I'm using an HSQLDB to store data and the app is written all in Java (JDBC, JavaServlets, JSP).

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with this requirement from a design perspective.  First, how do I store these lists in the database?  Would each list be its own table?  Having each list be a column in one table seems wrong (wouldn't that violate normalization rules?).  I'm not super familiar with database design, but googling hasn't revealed a good solution to this.

Second, how do I treat these lists in my code?  I've been thinking of using static variables (Collections of some sort) in the associated classes, because these settings are meant to be global, not specific to one user or project.  That's generally not considered good design though.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.  I want to get the design correct not only because this is a software engineering class so design is important, but also because I may end up expanding this project into a master's project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is standard normalization.

create a list table

```
mylist
---------
option_id 
option_name
```

then associate it to the other table as appropriate

```
my_other_table
--------------
attributes...
option_id
```

the UI for setting values for my_other_table queries to mylist for the values that should go into the combo box or whatever UI component you choose.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

About the UI and querying, I'm going for a 3 tier architecture so the UI won't be calling the database directly.  The database access code will be its own class, which will be called by a servlet, which will make sure there's no malicious input and things like that.  I'm wondering how to handle the lists in the servlet code.

Comment: Also, do I need to have an id field in there? The individual values should all be unique, so would it be ok to just use the value as the primary key (and foreign key in the other tables)?

Comment: In addition, the option_id field in my_other_table should have FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES mylist(option_id) constraint. You handle the list in the servlet by performing a SELECT from the mylist and other list tables. You do need the id field, otherwise you will not be able to change "Master's paper" to "Master's thesis" with a simple update of the list (although if you define a foreign key with ON UPDATE CASCADE all the tables will be updated, but this will be a time consuming database operation)

Comment: No. Use an int ID. It's easier to use (no spaces or special characters to encore in request parameters and HTML), faster, and, above all, it avoids changing all the foreign keys when you decide to switch from "master's paper" to "master's thesis"

Comment: Thanks for the help, and sorry for the stupid questions...  As of a few weeks ago I'd never written so much as a query in SQL.  What I mean by "handle the list in the servlet" is how to store it.  Is storing it as a static variable in the class with which it's associated acceptable design?

Comment: you have 2 choices - if there is a one-to-one relationship, then store it in the class, if there are possibly many to many then create a new class for the association records.  In the OO world you will have arrays and lists, in the RDBMS world you will have tables and foreign keys to other tables. hth

Comment: Hmm.  What about a one-to-many relationship?  I believe that's what I'd have here, as each list is unique and used by all the objects of that class.  All projects have the same list of types, all tasks have the same list of priorities, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Each "enum" should be stored in its own table, so that you can have foreign keys to this table.

You could store all the possible values of each "enum" in a cache, to avoid going to the database each time you need the list of options, but be careful not to propose stale data. Since the number of entries should be very small, I wouldn't care much about performance until you have a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we have table Dictionary(class, field, value, description) - and for each class and field we have as many rows, as there are allowed values, and it works quite well.